# Google oauth .net how can I get valid credential?

Tags: .net, oauth, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I try to create an example from [Google OAuth documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc) but I cant get a valid Credential. 
In the OAuth callback controller I have override IndexAsync Method. But event I have an authorization code. My cansellation token everytime false. and a result I have null of the `result.Credential`

```
public override async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync(AuthorizationCodeResponseUrl authorizationCode, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
            AuthorizeAsync(taskCancellationToken);

     --> **result.Credential == null**

        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
            ApplicationName = "ASP.NET MVC Sample"
        });
        UsersResource.LabelsResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Labels.List("me");

        IList<Label> labels = request.Execute().Labels;

        var a = request;
        return View();
    }
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you stumbled across this useful [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet)?

Comment: Yes, But this  example for console application. I`m using asp.net mvc and OAuth.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you have said, you are using [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#oauth-20-protocol). There is a basic pattern for accessing a Google API using OAuth 2.0. It follows 4 steps:

- Obtain OAuth 2.0 credentials from the Google Developers Console.
- Obtain an access token from the Google Authorization Server.
- Send the access token to an API.
- Refresh the access token, if necessary.

For more details, you can follow the tutorial here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#handlingtheresponse

You have to visit the Google Developers Console to obtain OAuth 2.0 credentials such as a client ID and client secret that are known to both Google and your application

Addition to @Tholle answer, go through the [Official Google Document](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet). Just complete the steps described in the rest of page and in about five minutes you'll have a simple .NET console application that makes requests to the Gmail API.

Comment: Hey man, that's a very shitty answer. Guy has got a problem following Google's example and you're giving him some generic info and irrelevant links (tutorial for 'installed app' is useless in case of  MVC app - and he has used official documentation)

Comment: This isn't a constructive or helpful answer - "just read the docs" doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

So it's hard to tell what's going wrong here without more info, but I had the same problem, and this is what caused it for me.

The  AppFlowMetadata creates a new instance of GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow. This takes an Initializer object, and inside that object you define the DataStore for storing the tokens.

If you don't define that DataStore, or if something doesn't work properly inside that Datastore so that the tokens aren't stored, it leads to this behavior where the credential returns null every time.

So I would start checking if your DataStore is properly configured.